# Train Reservations in Spain (with pass)

Tags: trains, spain

I need to book a seat on a train from Barcelona to San Sebastian. The site I was using wants to send the ticket by post, but that will be too slow.

Is there a way I can do it electronically, or pick up the reservation at the station?

Comment: Which website are you using to book the ticket ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a pass don't bother with reserving in advance. Do it at the station once you are there.

You should not have bought a pass however. Somehow the idea that a Railpass is needed for train travel in Europe seems to be very hard to eradicate… So people buy a pass first, and then investigate reservation. What you should do however, is investigate first what tickets costs.

The [RENFE website](http://www.renfe.com/) will allow you to buy online tickets for some trains (Barcelona - San Sebastian) and those you can print out yourself. These tickets are, when booked in advance, usually a lot cheaper than a day on a railpass.